# Set random values from an array into database

Tags: php, mysql, database, random

I'm working on a PHP project with MYSQL database. I have a table of groups of students. Each group has an examiner. What i want to do is that i want to set two examiners for each group randomly. How to do it?

**MySQL Code:**

```
create table groups (
    groupID             int(10)               not null,
    nbStudents          int                   not null,
    avgGPA              DOUBLE                NOT NULL,
    projectName         varchar(50)           not null,
    advisorID           int,                  
    examiner1ID         int,    
    examiner2ID         int,
    adminID             int                   not null,
    primary key (groupID)
);

create table faculty (
    name                varchar(30)         not null,
    facultyID           int(10)                 not null,
    email               varchar(30)           not null,
    mobile              int(15)              not null,            
    primary key (facultyID)
);
```

`examiner1ID` and `examiner2ID` are foreign keys from the table faculty.

Comment: Edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: And throw in some source code while you're at it

Comment: Do you have an Examiners table?

Comment: can the same faculty member be assigned to multiple groups?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very convoluted way to do it. It uses 2 subqueries to pick faculty members, and `insert .. on duplicate key` to update the examiners IDs.

```
insert into groups
(groupID, examiner1ID, examiner2ID)
select groupID, 
    @x:=(select facultyID from faculty order by rand() limit 1),
    (select facultyID from faculty where facultyID <> @x order by rand() limit 1)
from groups
on duplicate key update examiner1ID=values(examiner1ID), examiner2ID=values(examiner2ID);
```

`@x` is a [user-defined-variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html). In this case, it is used to store the first random faculty member. `<> @x` makes sure we don't pick the same faculty member in both slots.

Since `groupID` is a unique key, when we try to insert a row with an existing unique key, it will update the existing row instead of inserting it. That's what `on duplicate key update` clause is used for.

set different examiners for each group:

```
insert into groups
(groupID, examier1ID, examier2ID)
select a.groupID, max(if(b.id%2, b.facultyID, 0)), max(if(b.id%2, 0, b.facultyID))
from (
    select @row:=@row+1 id, groupID 
    from groups a
    join (select @row:=0) b) a
join (
    select @row:=@row+1 id, facultyID
    from (
        select facultyID
        from faculty a
        order by rand()) a
    join (select @row:=0) b) b on a.id = ceil(b.id/2)
group by a.groupID
on duplicate key update examiner1ID=values(examiner1ID), examiner2ID=values(examiner2ID);
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain what you just did? What is @x: and <> ? What is on duplicate key?

Comment: Thanks dude. Last thing. How to set different examiners for each group? No duplicates. Thanks.

Comment: @hzjw, you mean the same faculty member cannot be assigned to multiple groups?